# Is there a way to make parallax work within a DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

May be completely barking up the wrong tree but can you make a parallax scrolling image using a div background-image element?

What I want to happen is I currently have some DIVs with images with a text effect rollover but I as I'm using parallax in a background image I want to keep the 3D theme with all the sites images.

EDIT: For example, is it possible to make the blue boxes on this page:

www.parkhallmanor.co.uk/new

Scroll separate images using a parallax effect?

Comment: This question is a little confusing. Do you want to make a parallax effect happen inside a div, or do you already have one parallax effect on the entire page, and want another in some smaller area on mouseover... or something else?

Comment: ok the best way to show is to visit www.parkhallmanor.co.uk/new and you will be blue windows I want to make the same effect happen within each DIV "windows" with images

Comment: Are you trying to use a single image that scrolls in those windows and the top bar, or separate images in each of the blue windows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

As you presumably know a normal parallax effect just puts a bg image on the body tag and either changes its background offset as you scroll, or moves some divs on top of it slower than the scroll rate.

Since you want separate images in each of the windows, you need to go with the background offset approach. Each div is just something like this in CSS:

```
#div1 {
    background: url('/ui/div1bg.jpg') 0 -800px no-repeat;
}
```

The `0 -800px` are the [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp). As the window scrolls down you want to shift the backgrounds downward by increasing that second value gradually, to simulate perspective. In simulated perspective, farther things move slowly past you, close things move quickly.

So you just get the scroll event:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    parallax();
});
```

Gather the metrics you'll be using:

```
function parallax() {
    var ev = {
        scrollTop: document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop
    };
    ev.ratioScrolled = ev.scrollTop / (document.body.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    render(ev);
}
```

And render the changes:

```
function render(ev) {
    var t = ev.scrollTop;
    var y = Math.round(t * 2/3) - 800;
    $('#div1, #div2, #div3').css('background-position', '0 ' + y + 'px');
}
```

So, as the t variable increases (user scrolls down), the image shifts at 2/3 the rate. It starts at -800px and gradually makes its way to 0 once the user has scrolled to 1200px down. If the page is longer than 1200px AND the element is still visible you'll have to adjust the math, since after that the code is going to scroll past the top of the image. If they'll already be past the element by that point though, you can ignore it.

Obviously you should adjust the numbers there to get the right effect for your divs and images.

If you want to base it on the total page height no matter what it happens to be, you can use the second metric up there, .ratioScrolled, like:

```
var y = Math.round((1 - ev.ratioScrolled) * -100);
```

So for example if you had a div with height 150px, and an image 250px tall, the above would work perfectly - it starts at -100px (shifted up) and as the page scrolls by, no matter how long it happens to be, it ends at 0px (no shift - so the bottom 100px is clipped).

Comment: This is almost there how do I slow the movement even more as I the images im using are not massively long, is there a way to limit how far it can go?

Comment: Updated my answer with a way to calculate the ratio scrolled

Comment: This is superb you have really made my day! thank you so much

Comment: Quick question though, how would i reverse the movement?

Comment: No problem. Reverse like make it move in the opposite direction in response to scrolling? Just change one of the numbers from negative to positive. Math!

Comment: lol thats what I did but now I can't get my image to sit at the top of the DIV

Comment: You'll have to think through the math to effectively play with the animation. Remember you can use either px (as I used in my example) or %, and if you stick with px you'll want to consider the height of the actual image and shift it accordingly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26340/discussion-between-joseph-gregory-and-chris-moschini)