# Parallax on Div center vertically and positioned absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In a project, I have a div which take 100% height and 100% width of the window thanks to a script I've wrote (with jQuery, and called on window resize too).

Inside this div, I have an other div which contains a title(H3) and a paragraph(P). This div is centered vertically et horizontally in this 100% parent div.

Now, I want to add a parallax effect on the child div. I mean I want that on scroll, the div moves slower than his parent div. How could I achieve that ? I've tried to wrote it myself but it doesn't work...

My try :

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    parallax();
});

function parallax() {
  var ev = {
      scrollTop: document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop
  };
  ev.ratioScrolled = ev.scrollTop / (document.body.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  render(ev);
}

function render(ev) {
    var t = ev.scrollTop;
    var obj = $('.topBonjour .wrapper');
    var top = parseInt(obj.css('top'));

    if (t > lastScrollTop) {
      newTop = top + 1;
      $('.topBonjour .wrapper').css('top', newTop +'px');
    } else {
      newTop = top - 1;
      $('.topBonjour .wrapper').css('top', newTop +'px');
    }    
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Cédric

Comment: you don't have to use a script to make a dive take 100% width & height of the view port. its very simple in CSS. also: post a live fiddle of your relevant code. and if you can explain more about what you're trying to achieve. what 'more slowly then the parent' means.

Comment: Read the answer here, it helped me a lot!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465481/is-there-a-way-to-make-parallax-work-within-a-div

Comment: Possibly you forgot to set position of those element to relative so the css on *top* works.