# Parallax Effect Adjustment for individual DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I created a parallax effect, as it was described here:
[Is there a way to make parallax work within a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465481/is-there-a-way-to-make-parallax-work-within-a-div)

This method works pretty well, but I have a problem with it. My page is basically composed of alternating DIVs. White DIVs with text and DIVs with a picture in it, which moves with the parallax effect. This works pretty well, unless, that I have to manually adjust the position of each picture DIV. Here is the code from the header:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        parallax();
    });
    function parallax() {
    var ev = {
        scrollTop: document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop
    };
    ev.ratioScrolled = ev.scrollTop / (document.body.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    render(ev);
    }
    function render(ev) {
    var t = ev.scrollTop;
    var y = Math.round(t * 2/3) - 100;
    $('#ff-section01').css('background-position', 'center ' + y + 'px');
    $('#ff-section03').css('background-position', 'center ' + (y - 1000) + 'px');
    $('#ff-section05').css('background-position', 'center ' + (y - 1700) + 'px');
    $('#ff-section07').css('background-position', 'center ' + (y - 2750) + 'px');
    }
    </script>
```

As you can see, each section got another vertical position in the background-position value at the bottom. 0, 1000, 1700, 2750. This works well so far, but as soon as the intermediate Text DIVs change in height, this method doesn't work, as the value is always calculated from the top of the page. The HTML of one section looks like this:

```
<div class="ff-section03" id="ff-section03"></div>
```

So very simple, and combined with the CSS:

```
.ff-section03 {
    width: 100%; height: 550px;
    position: relative;
    background: url('system/urbansolutions.jpg') center -300px no-repeat;
}
```

Also very simple. What can I do, that the calculations are not dependent of the page height? I basically don't want to subtract a superficial number from the background-position, so that the parallax effect works, not dependent of the location on the website.

Thanks a lot!
Sebastian